# How to clone an Xcode projects?

Tags: xcode, clone

I've created a generic Xcode project with basic functionality from which I want to build multiple other projects.  How can I clone the generic project and begin the specific functionality in a new project instance?

Comment: You could just copy the whole project folder.

Answer (score 0):

I did similar for a few projects. Copy the entire folder, make sure the libraries are still synced and away you go. 
I did the same for both c++ and obj c projects and had no problems with either when doing this.